# Frida: DebugSymbol.fromAddress produces objects with null fields

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, frida

I'm using Frida to run this command on my iPhone 7 (iOS 14.4):

`frida-trace -U -S lib.js -m "-[NSMutableURLRequest setValue*]" --decorate -f com.apple.AppStore`

`lib.js` contains this simple helper function:

```
function backtrace() {
    return '\tBacktrace:\n\t' +
            Thread.backtrace(this.context, Backtracer.ACCURATE)
                .map(item => {
                    var symbol = DebugSymbol.fromAddress(item);
                    return JSON.stringify(symbol);
                })
                .join('\n\t');
}
```

And then in `onEnter` of the produced handler I do this:

`log(backtrace());`

And all I see in the terminal is:

```
  1400 ms       Backtrace:
        {"address":"0x1069bb294","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x1069f92c4","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x106a02024","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x106a02f2c","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x106a02ddc","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x106a01d2c","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x1069f92c4","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x106a02024","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x106a02f2c","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x106a02f2c","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x106a01d2c","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x1069afaf8","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x1069afbf4","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x1069c0770","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x10695eca0","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
        {"address":"0x104cd407c","name":null,"moduleName":null,"fileName":null,"lineNumber":null}
```

Why is this happening and how can I get module and method names of the call stack items?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience `DebugSymbol.fromAddress()` does not work very good on some iOS apps. I even encountered that applying this method on a stack trace was causing an app crash. Not sure why it does not work, could be a bug or the app binary just misses debug symbols.

Alternatively for understanding the stack trace you can map each address to the module it belongs to using Frida's [ModuleMap](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#modulemap)

```
var moduleMap = new ModuleMap();
var backtrace = Thread.backtrace(this.context, Backtracer.ACCURATE); 
return backtrace.map(addr => return moduleMap.get(addr).name).join('\n\t');
```

Then you still miss the method name, I don't know how to get it in such a situation.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't work - seems that module map doesn't have those addresses. I checked it using `moduleMap.has(address)`. I think I'll try this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/68335254/3405844