# Unable to find JNI function with frida (android)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, frida

I have the following class in android app:

```
package com.app.s;

public final class Api {
    public native int func(String str, String str2);

    ...
    ...
    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("nativelib");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            Log.e("lib", "fail:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

In `libnativelib.so`: function `Java_com_app_s_Api_func` is calling `target_func`

I'm trying to access `target_func` variables
However I'm unable to locate the loaded module with frida

I've tried the following with frida:

**try 1** - does not print the library name

```
var allModules = Process.enumerateModules()
for(var i=0;i<allModules.length;i++){ 
  console.log(allModules[i].name); 
}
```

**try 2** - Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Java_com_app_s_Api"

```
Java.perform(function() {
  var it = setInterval(function(){
    try{
      var hook = Java.use("Java_com_app_s_Api");
      console.log("info: hooking target class");

      hook.func.overload().implementation = function() {
                console.log("[+] func")

                var ret = this.func()
                console.log("[*] retval: " + ret)
                return ret

      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },200); // runs every 200milisecods
});
```

**try 3** - doesn't print the functions in the library although they are being called

```
frida-trace -U -i "Java_*" -f <app>
```

**try 4 (error)** - loading `findExportByName` with `dlopen` frida snippet as suggested by Robert

```
   dlopen called with: libandroid.so
    dlopen called with: /system/lib64/libEGL.so
    dlopen called with: /system/lib64/libGLESv1_CM.so
    dlopen called with: /system/lib64/libGLESv2.so
    dlopen called with: /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
    Process crashed: Trace/BPT trap
    
    ***
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_x86_64/emu64xa:14/UE1A.230829.036.A1/11228894:userdebug/dev-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'x86_64'
    Timestamp: 2024-02-24 17:01:44.281739700+0000
    Process uptime: 4s
    Cmdline: com.app
    pid: 5917, tid: 5986, name: RenderThread  >>> com.app <<<
    uid: 10192
    signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
    Abort message: 'Failed to create context, error = EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED'
```

**try 5**

```
Java.perform(function() {
    var flag = false;
    try{
      Java.use("com.app.s.Api");
      var allModules = Process.enumerateModules()
        for(var i=0;i<allModules.length;i++){ 
            if(allModules[i].name.includes("nativelib")){
                console.log(allModules[i].name); 
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if(!flag){
            console.log("not found");
        }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Do you have any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems:

#### Finding module `libnativelib.so`

`libnativelib.so` is only loaded when the Java class `com.app.s.Api` is loaded. This happens when this class is used for the first time.

Best way would be to hook the `static {...` part of that class (that would be the method `<clinit>`). Unfortunately I don't know if Frida does support hooking clinit method, some older versions seem to had problems doing so, not sure about recent versions.

Therefore My recommendation would be to hook in Java class `java.lang.System` the `loadLibrary` method to check when the library you are searching is loaded.

Once it is loaded you could directly install the hook for `target_func`.

#### Hooking Java_com_app_s_Api

`Java_com_app_s_Api` is not a Java class, it is the name of a native JNI  function that implements a function that can be called from Java as it would be a Java function (which it is not). Therefore `Java.use("Java_com_app_s_Api")` will never work. What can work is `Java.use("com.app.s.Api")`

So you can try to create a Java hook for class `com.app.s.Api` for the JNI method `func(String str, String str2)` or you create an native hook using [Interceptor.attach](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#interceptor) on the C function `Java_com_app_s_Api_func` (see example [here](https://github.com/iddoeldor/frida-snippets/blob/master/README.md#hook-jni-by-address)).

#### Hook `target_func`

I assume `target_func` is not a function that is exported by the library. Therefore you have to use identify and use the address of the function. For doing so you need an external tool like Ghidra or IDA Pro to get the address of the function. At run-time you can then calculate the address you need to hook. More details can be found in the question and my answer to it [frida hook native non exported functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68332781/150978)

#### Sample code

In total I would recommend to you to follow the [frida-snippet JNI hook example](https://github.com/iddoeldor/frida-snippets/blob/master/README.md#hook-jni-by-address):

```
var moduleName = "libfoo.so"; 
var nativeFuncAddr = 0x1234; // get the address via Ghidra/IDA/...

Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, "dlopen"), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        this.lib = Memory.readUtf8String(args[0]);
        console.log("dlopen called with: " + this.lib);
    },
    onLeave: function(retval) {
        if (this.lib.endsWith(moduleName)) {
            console.log("ret: " + retval);
            var baseAddr = Module.findBaseAddress(moduleName);
            Interceptor.attach(baseAddr.add(nativeFuncAddr), {
                onEnter: function(args) {
                    console.log("[-] hook invoked");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify({
                        a1: args[1].toInt32(),
                        a2: Memory.readUtf8String(Memory.readPointer(args[2])),
                        a3: Boolean(args[3])
                    }, null, '\t'));
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, I've tried the snippet and I've edited my post in response.

Comment: @Dinamo As I wrote the library you want to hook a function in is somewhen loaded at run-time. So you first have to find-out when this happens. Or you can try to enforce loading by calling `Java.use("com.app.s.Api")` note that in this case all hooks will not trigger as hooks only trigger if frida is not involved (regular call from within the app). Never tried this but enumerating the modules after calling `Java.use("com.app.s.Api")` should contain the library you are searching.

Comment: The library is definitely running when I run the script, I can see the logcat output of it, I tried to enumerate after `Java.use("com.app.s.Api")` and I can't locate the library, also I did subtract imagebase from the function address that was found in ghidra `var nativeFuncAddr = func_addr - imagebaseGhidra`, What is the best way to examine the memory in order to find out what is wrong?

Comment: @Dinamo Just a guess: you are using an emulator. If the app is loaded as arm with in-emulator translation to x86 then a lot of things can go wrong, Please always use a physical Arm64 Device.